# How to mock a variable inside a Jest test function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express, jestjs

I'm testing the Express application with Jest and came across a slight problem - the module uses variable that is initialized before the test execution, here is my **app.js** file:

```
const app = express();
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  if (isDev) {
    res.status(404).json({ error: 'Wrong URL' });
  } else {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../index.html'));
  }
});

app.use(errorHandler);

module.exports = app;
```

When I run Jest tests, my `process.env.NODE_ENV` is equal to `test`, that's why I can't cover the first `if` condition, where `isDev` is `true`.
I've tried to reassign `process.env.NODE_ENV` before the test request - it works, but as `isDev` variable initialization has been done before test execution, it didn't work.

This is my test:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');

describe('GET /*', () => {
  const OLD_ENV = process.env;

  beforeEach(() => {
    // Clear JEST cache
    jest.resetModules();
    process.env = { ...OLD_ENV };
    Reflect.deleteProperty(process.env, 'NODE_ENV');
  });

  test('Not existing path (development env) - 404 status', async () => {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

    const response = await request(app).
      get('/wrongUrl');
    expect(response.status).toBe(404);

  });

});
```

How can I mock the `isDev` variable inside my test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [jest.isolateModules(fn)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestisolatemodulesfn) to app in isolation like this:

```
describe("GET /*", () => {
  describe("on development", () => {
    let app;
    beforeAll(() => {
      process.env.NODE_ENV = "development";
      jest.isolateModules(() => {
        app = require("../app");
      });
    });

    it("should to this", () => {
      expect(app).....
    });
  });

  describe("on production", () => {
    let app;
    beforeAll(() => {
      process.env.NODE_ENV = "production";
      jest.isolateModules(() => {
        app = require("../app");
      });
    });

    it("should to that", () => {
      expect(app())....
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `.env` file just for testing.
If you are using `express` you could also use `dotenv`.
With this package you can import env variables from different files.

Just add this line at the top of your file.

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: process.cwd() + '/path/to/test.env' });
```

This way you can always change the env variables you want to use, before every test.

Comment: What if you want to cover the both branches with and without the environment variable ?